# Facing issue while hitting back end hosted on AWS port 5000

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I am not able to make request to python back end which is hosted on AWS port 5000 from cordova app(trying to access it from javascript through jquery ajax). 
I want to access http://MY_AWS_IP:5000 but getting readyState 0, also I am able to access API hosted on heroku https://reqres.in/api/users/2.
Request you help. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ankit

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    //url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2',
    url: 'http://MY_AWS_IP:5000',
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert('success'+ response);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
        console.log(xhr.readyState);
                    alert(xhr.readyState);
            }
       });
```

Comment: If this IP is an ec2 instance check the security groups is setup to allow port 5000

Comment: All necessary settings have been done to allow port 5000 in ec2 instance